# mysqli_error "doesn't have a default value"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on upgrading a site's server from PHP 5.2.17 to 5.5 to keep it fresh from upgrades in the future and to install other software that requires PHP 5.4+.

The database has one table that I'm testing where there are a number of columns that are edited after an initial `INSERT` query.

I'm also upgrading the `mysql_connect` function to `mysqli_connect`, as it's more secure.

I guess one of the drawbacks is that you now have to provide default values for every column of the table when performing an `INSERT`.

Is there any way to bypass that or do you just have to provide defaults all the time now?

Comment: There is no difference in default column values for a database between MySQL and MySQLi... aside from using bind vars rather than injecting values directly in your statement, the SQL syntax should be exactly the same

Comment: Well I wasn't getting the error before the PHP upgrade.

Comment: Also, switch to the [MySQLi Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php). This way you won't get caught up with stringy code.

Comment: You should always include the column list in an insert anyway. If you don't, your insert will break when you add a column to the table. It creates a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: If you weren't getting the error before, and you are now, then you've made a mistake in your conversion somewhere

Comment: Perhaps your MySQL server version was updated too, and not providing default values for columns that require one might now be throwing you an error. You could update your DB schema and provide default values (blank or null etc) for those columns...

Comment: show us the new code you use that breaks.

Comment: Mark is right, there is no difference between MySQL and MySQLi. Are you sure that these columns allow a NULL value? If not and no value is provided then you'll get an error along those lines.

Comment: If you have a column in your MySQL database called `timestamp`, simply avoiding that column in the `INSERT` query will set its default value.

Comment: `I'm also upgrading the mysql_connect function to mysqli_connect, as it's more secure.`- that's but a grave delusion. it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're saying, I suspect your MySQL version has also been upgraded - probably to 5.6.

I've seen this problem occur in that scenario, but only after upgrading the database; to be clear, I was using PDO rather than either of the mysql*_ variants, but the end result was the same.